# Can't install windows beacause the disk is of the GPT partition style

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I have read on the internet that I should enter `diskpart` and then select the disk I want to install Windows on and use command `clean`. But that command is going to erase all of my data, and I need that data. Here are the pictures to explain my problem:

Here I can see both, the partition with data I need and the unallocated space I want to install windows on

[image: My both drives]

And here is what I see from cmd when I enter `diskpart`, it merges both partitions into one and that is why I can't use `clean`

[image: Result after diskpart]

Also, when I try to create new partition of unallocated space I get an error.

Comment: In `diskpart` you need to `select disk 0` then `list part`: you should then see the partitions in your other list, though I see no immediate reason that Windows cannot install here: it is certainly nothing to do with GPT. What do you see when you click `Show details`?

Comment: Next message: Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style.
When I use list part, as you said, I can see only 365GB, the partition with data, but I don't see unallocated space. Why is that?

Comment: Actually I see it as offset

Comment: I can't say at the moment: you'll need to expand your answer with these details.

Comment: I have used create partition EFI and now it is installing windows. I just hope that I didn't lose data from other partition. Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't have lost data, but equally you should have backed up before embarking on the installation: it is foolhardy to hope that nothing will go wrong. But of course if the data are valuable you will have been backing up regularly, won't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows ties its boot mode and partition table type quite inflexibly:

- If you boot the installer in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, you can install to [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) disks *only.*
- If you boot the installer in EFI/UEFI mode, you can install to [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) disks *only.*

Your disk is a GPT disk, and the message you're seeing indicates that you've booted the installer in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode (or on a BIOS-only computer); it's complaining about the mismatch. Note that GPT and MBR are both partition table types. As such, they apply to the *entire* disk; you can't convert just one partition from GPT to MBR or vice-versa. (Well, aside from hybrid MBRs, but that topic is irrelevant here.) Broadly speaking, there are two solutions:

- **Boot in EFI mode** -- Instead of booting the installer in BIOS mode, you can boot it in EFI mode -- *if* your computer uses EFI firmware, as do most computers sold since late 2011 or thereabouts. The trick to this approach is in getting the Windows installer to boot in EFI mode. This may require adjusting your firmware's boot options (such as disabling the CSM), picking the correct boot option (typically one with the string "UEFI" along with the brand name of the USB boot drive), or re-creating the boot medium. All these topics are covered on [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html), but be aware it's written with a Linux audience in mind. (Most of the principles apply to Windows, but some details differ.)
- **Convert the disk to MBR** -- Some disk disk partitioning tools can convert from GPT to MBR or vice-versa without trashing your data. My own [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr) can do this. So can some Windows-specific tools that may be easier to use, but I'm afraid I'm not familiar with them and so I can't provide any pointers. Beware, though: Some tools, including the standard Microsoft tools, can convert from GPT to MBR or vice-versa only by wiping out your existing partitions! If you convert your disk, you can boot the installer just as you did before and you should be able to install. One caveat: Although a lossless conversion from GPT to MBR is theoretically possible, program bugs, power losses at inopportune times, user error, and other things can wipe out your partition table when you work at this low level. Thus, the risk is not 0, and you should back up your important data before you try this.

Which approach to take depends on details you've not presented, such as:

- **Is your computer EFI-based?** If it's not, you can't choose the first option.
- **Do you have another OS installed elsewhere?** If so, you should try to install Windows in the same mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI) as the first OS. Mixing OS boot modes is possible, but it's an extra complication and it can be a hassle to set up.
- **What's the disk's sector size?** The vast majority of disks have 512-byte logical sectors. (Many have 4096-byte *physical* sectors, but that's irrelevant.) A few disks have 4096-byte logical sectors, though, and AFAIK such disks can't be used as boot disks in BIOS mode. Given your disk's size, it almost certainly has 512-byte logical sectors, but if it's in an external enclosure, it might use 4096-byte logical sectors.
- **Do you need GPT features?** GPT offers some modest advantages over MBR, such as better error checking and correction, a limit of 128 partitions by default (vs. 4 primary partitions for MBR), and so on. (Its biggest advantage is that it can be used with disks over 2 TiB in size, but that's irrelevant for your disk.) Chances are you don't need any of these things, but if you do, you should favor GPT.